# Angular Micro Frontend micro-app's services url keeps getting replaced by Shell app's url

Tags: angular, angular-services, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

In my Nx workspace, I have 2 Angular apps where I am using Webpack Module Federation to create a Micro Frontend architecture. Standalone the micro-apps works fine, however, when they are routed to via the shell app URLs for their services are replaced by Shell app's URL

i.e

shell app url localhost:3000
micro-app url localhost:4000
micro-app-api urls are replaced as localhost:3000/api-url/... instead of maintaining its path localhost:4000/api-url/...

Comment: So do you have a runtime config containing those urls in the host?

Comment: @MikeOne no I don't, I thought that Micro-app services would maintain the url it's currently running on even if it's routed to in the Shell-app.

Comment: It’s hard to say what exactly is happening without knowing where you get those url’s from. If they are set relatively in the remotes, it’s logical that they use the host urls as - after all - that is the url your remote runs under..?

Comment: @MikeOne I am using proxy config files; the shell app has it's own separate proxy config file and so does each the micro-app

Comment: Right. Well the shell (and therefore also the remotes running in the shell) will take the proxy config from the shell. You realise that the angular proxy only works for ng serve right? So you really want to run your API on dedicated endpoints (if you ever want to deploy this - you'll need that anyway)

Comment: @MikeOne so are you suggesting that I use relative paths direct to the hosted APIs instead of going through the proxy config?

Comment: Absolute paths is what you need..

Answer (score 0):

I see it's been some time over this question, but I had the same issue and updating build command in package.json to set base-href and deploy-url resolved the issue.

Try adding `--base-href http://localhost:4000/ --deploy-url http://localhost:4000/` to the build command.
Hope it helps.